# Hiding modal when form submitted and refresh main page

Tags: javascript

I want to hide my modal when form submitted and auto renew my main page.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  type: "post",
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json"
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url('Welcome/create_post'); ?>",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function() {
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
      }
    });
  })
})
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your question?

Comment: sry...i've created a page with a button, when the button pressed it call file popup with form.... my program run till form submitted and saved in db, but popup still appear and need manual reload to refresh my main page... i want popup closed automatically and main page content renew automatically... sry my bad eng

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: "post",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json"
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url('Welcome/create_post'); ?>",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
              $('.main-page').html(data);
              $('.modal').hide();
            }
        });
    })
})
```

Notice the 'data' variable I've added to the success callback function, this var contains the response of your ajax call. To hide an element using jQuery the proper syntax is: $("someElement").hide();

Comment: ty for ur responses, but it still the same

Comment: check the data you are getting returned and if it is a success (200).  it will not return data to the success function if there is an error.